# How do I force Android Camera app to use back camera?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-camera, android-camera-intent

I have a function called `openCamera` that creates and starts an intent to take a photo with Android's camera app. This is the code:

```
private fun openCamera() {
    Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE).also { takePictureIntent ->
        // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
        takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(packageManager)?.also {
            // Create the File where the photo should go
            photoFile = createImageFile()

            // Continue only if the File was successfully created
            photoFile.also {
                photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                    Objects.requireNonNull(applicationContext),
                    BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",
                    photoFile
                )
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI)
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When my app opens the camera app, how do I force the camera app to open using the back camera instead of the front camera?

Comment: Which camera(s) to offer to the user, and which to use by default, is up to the developers of the particular camera app that the user chooses, among the hundreds of possible camera apps (pre-installed and user-installed).

Comment: @CommonsWare Can you elaborate on that? Does that mean since some users default camera app isn't the pre-installed Android app it's not possible to start the camera using the back side of the phone?

Comment: First, there is no single "pre-installed Android app". There are dozens upon dozens of them, spread across the 26,000+ Android device models. There are countless others available for download from the Play Store and elsewhere. `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` does not offer any extras to control things like which camera to use, in part due to the breadth of camera apps. If you need that sort of control, take the pictures yourself, using CameraX or another camera library (CameraKit-Android, Fotoapparat, etc.).